# Problem with quicksort and python

Tags: python, sorting

I'm writing a python program that plays poker for a class, and I need to sort a list of five card hands. I have a function called wins(), which takes two hands and returns True if the first one beats the second one, False if it doesn't. I wrote an implementation of quicksort to sort the list of hands, and I noticed that it was taking much longer than expected, so I programmed it to print the length of each list it was sorting. The function looks like this:

```
def sort(l):
    if len(l) <= 1:
        return l
    print len(l)
    pivot = choice(l)
    l.remove(pivot)
    left = []
    right = []
    for i in l:
        if wins(i, pivot) == True:
            right.append(i)
        else:
            left.append(i)
    return sort(left) + [pivot] + sort(right)
```

and when I had it sort 64 hands, it printed:
64,
53,
39,
26,
25,
24,
23,
22,
21,
20,
19,
18,
17,
16,
15,
14,
13,
12,
11,
10,
9,
8,
7,
6,
5,
4,
3,
2,
12,
7,
3,
2,
3,
2,
4,
3,
2,
13,
9,
6,
2,
3,
2,
2,
3,
10,
8,
2,
5,
4,
3,
2. Notice the consecutive sequence in the middle? I can't figure out why it does that, but it's causing quicksort to behave like an O(n^2). It doesn't make sense for it to choose the strongest hand as a pivot on every iteration, but that's what seems to be happening. What am I overlooking?

Comment: Why are you writing your own sort? Doesn't python have a sort function of its own?

Comment: I'm not sorting numbers, I'm sorting poker hands.

Comment: It appears the thing to do is [create a lambda](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting) to sort tuples or named objects.

Comment: How would this be done? Sorry, I forgot to mention, I'm very new to programming.

Comment: Right, there's a link. I get it.

Comment: I'm not a python person at all, so can't help you there (that would also be a question for Stack Overflow). If you are new to programming, why are you trying to implement quicksort? If this is for a class, have you asked your instructor? The ways we do things may be completely wrong for an academic setting.

Comment: This belongs on stack overflow, where it will probably get migrated soon.  However, note that if you think the problem is in the choice of pivot, it would probably help if you actually posted your `choice` function.

Comment: I needed a sorted list of poker hands, and I figured since I am learning things, I may as well try to implement to myself, if only to learn how. I can't figure out how to apply python's built in sorting to something that isn't numerical.

Comment: My choice function is python's built-in random.choose

Answer (score 0):

Edited answer after comments:

Could you try the following code and share your results. It introduces an equivalence class to reduce the population in the "lose or tie" (or "smaller than or equal to") group while forming an answer via recursion.

```
# modified quicksort with equivalence class.
def sort(l):
    if len(l) <= 1:
        return l
    print len(l)
    pivot = choice(l)
    l.remove(pivot)
    left = []
    right = []

    # I added an equivalence class
    pivotEquivalence = [pivot] 

    # and an equivalence partitioning 
    # to reduce number of elements 
    # in the upcoming recursive calls
    for i in l:
        if wins(i, pivot) == True:
            right.append(i)
        elif wins(pivot,i) == True:
            left.append(i)
        else 
            pivotEquivalence.append(i)
    return sort(left) + pivotEquivalence + sort(right)
```

======

Instead of choosing the pivot randomly, try taking the middle indexed element. on average it will guarantee the O(N log N).

Also for O notation, you need to make many simulations to collect empirical data. Just one example might be very misleading.

Try to print the pivot, and it's index as well. Shuffle your list by random.shuffle(list) and try again to see the distribution. Just ensure system time seeding as well.

Could you send post the complete code, and your data for community to repeat the problem?

Sincerely,
Umut

Comment: I've tried choosing the pivot every way I can. On average, I recognize that, given a randomly chosen pivot, it should be O(n log n). That doesn't help the fact that it isn't. Also, why will choosing the middle indexed element for a pivot be more likely to work?

Comment: Why do you think random will work better than the fixed middle point selection? Due to probability of selected permutation of an unsorted list, they are pretty much equal cases for the algorithmic complexity. Ref: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort . If it is not very sensitive please provide a your functions and data for testing, so it will be possible to analyze your problem.

Comment: Why do you think fixed middle point selection will work better? I've tried both, and they are the same, they both fail reliably. I gave you my sort function, I told you it uses a function called wins(a, b), which I know works. If the quick sort algorithm fails every single time, which it does, and the probability of this happening by chance is one in 2^64, which it is, and I've done this hundreds of times, which I have, there has to be something wrong with my algorithm, something that I am asking you to help me find, which you're not doing. Please stop telling me that it should be working.

Comment: A fixed middle point might be faster to calculate than asking for a random number, and you might be also struggling with the performance. Even you stated out that your comparison function works, it is hard to find the "bug" without actually executing. Anyhow, I will edit the answer, and include some code for you to try. According to your results, I can make more educated guesses.

Comment: Thank you, and I'm sorry for getting so angry, it really was unjustified. How would I post the code here?

Comment: I understand, It happens to the best of us as well. No hearts broken. You can go to your original post and edit your question, so for future researchers, the problem will be available in the first instance as well. I think the best way is to upload it to GitHub or a service equivalent, and share the repository link. Thanks.